# Use a Int received by JSON in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

My php send a JSON object that contains an associative array with only one field called `check`. This field contains either `1` or `0`. I want use this integer to create an alert the value is `0`. I tried to create an external method var called log, where I try to give name's value, but it doesn't work.

```
@IBAction func LogIn(sender: UIButton) {

    let verify = 0

    let bodyString = "a=\(User_log.text!)&b=\(Password_log.text!)"
    let bodyData = bodyString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://mysite/myFolder/login.php")!)
    request.HTTPBody = bodyData
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if data == nil {
            print("request failed \(error)")
        }

        do{
            let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? [String: Int]
            if let name = json!["check"] {
                if name == verify{
                    log = 0
                }
                else{
                    log = 1
                }
            }
        }catch {
            print("bom bom bom error")
        }
    }
    task.resume()

}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Please be describe the issue you're facing in more details.

Comment: Does the server really return an `Int`?

Comment: The JSON is like { check = 1} . Whit the code: if let name = json!["check"] ; name now have the value 1. i want to use this value after task.resume()

Comment: `1` could be also `"1"` aka `String`. On the PHP side `json_encode()` does not necessarily convert numeric (string) values to integer.

Answer (score 0):

`NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData` gives you `[String: AnyObject]` not `[String: Int]`. Also, value for "check" would be `NSNumber` not `Int`

Please, try the following:

```
let data = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(["check": "1", "other": "test"], options: NSJSONWritingOptions.init(rawValue: 0))

var log = 0

if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as? [String: AnyObject] {
    log = json["check"]?.integerValue ?? 0
}
```

Comment: How do you create log variable? I assumed that you define `var log: Int` somewhere outside of method in initial snippet. I updated example which I checked in the playground.

Comment: `JSONObjectWithData` returns `AnyObject`

Comment: Yes, but it is actually possible to cast it to [String: AnyObject]

Comment: Indeed, but *it is actually possible to cast it* also *to* [String: Int], and `NSNumber` is implicitly bridged to `Int` (and vice versa), there's no need for the `NSNumber.integerValue` dance like in ObjC. The question is: what type does the server actually return?

Comment: If i print(json["check"]) The console give a right output 0 or 1, 0 if php query doesn't find a data in my db,1 if it find

Comment: You have to provide the option `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` in the `json_encode()` function to ensure that numeric strings are encoded as numbers in terms of JSON

Comment: You can cast it to [String: Int] dictionary only if json consists of pairs of strings and integers, but I described more generic case which handles json like `["check": 1, "name": "test"]`

Comment: I updated example which now works well in most generic case. It can handle the case if some non-integer data returned along with 'check' and also the case if value for 'check' was encoded as string.

Comment: I copied my example from swift playground where it worked as expected. Actually, this is how we parse JSON in our application.